# How to dynamically create a bootstrap dropdown based on data

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, mongodb, loops

So I am currently attempting to build a shopping cart application using the MEAN stack (mongodb/mongoose, express, ajax, node.js). Using bootstrap to build the site.

There are groups of products that can be created or destroyed so need to be dynamically created. I have a collection in my database called groups. It contains on field(groupName: 'movies') and than the id that mongo creates for it. So I need to go through the groups collection and for each group I find create a dropdown option for that group.

This is my controller for the page

```
//bring in models of data
var products = require('../models').Products;
var groups = require('../models').Groups;

//page functions go inside of module.exports
module.exports = {
    index: function(req, res){
        products.find({}, function(err, products){
            if(err){
                consol.log(err);
            }
            else{
                res.render('basic-page1', {dropdown: dropdown, title: 'Home', beforelogin: true, subtitle: 'Home', underheaderp: 'To search for products select a product group.'});

            }
        });
    }
}

var dropdown = function createSelect(){
    var dd = "";
    dd+= "<button class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown' id='dropdownProduct'>Please Select a Product Group<span class='caret'></span></button>";
    var group = groups.find({}, function(err, groups){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            dd+="<ul class='dropdown-menu col-xs-5'>";
            var i = 0;
            while(i <= group.length){
                dd+="<li><a href='#'>Hockey Jerseys</a></li>";
            }
                dd+="</ul>";
        }
    });
    return dd;
}
```

This code does not get any errors but does not print any of the dropdown options. The wile loop is were the problems are occurring.

When I change that loop to while(i < groups.length){..} or to while(i < 2){..} for testing purposes I get an error of
RangeError: Invalid string length

With further research of this error it does not seem to be very clear what exactly may be occurring.

Am I missing a step in the attempt to loop through the groups?

Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your createSelect is asynchronous and you are using it synchronously, which means `return dd` will always return `undefined`. Change it to this

```
function createSelect(callback){ 
    var dd = "";
    dd+= "<button class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown' id='dropdownProduct'>Please Select a Product Group<span class='caret'></span></button>"; 
    groups.find({}, function(err, groups){ 
        if(err){   
             console.log(err);
        }else{ 
            dd+="<ul class='dropdown-menu col-xs-5'>"; 

            for(var i=0; i< groups.length;i++){ 
              //dd+="<li><a href='#'>Hockey Jerseys</a></li>"; 
              // update
              dd+="<li><a href='#'>" + groups[i].groupName + "</a></li>";
            } 
            dd+="</ul>"; 
            callback(dd);
        } 
    }); 
}
```

And use it like this

```
....
createSelect(function(dropdown){
    res.render(....);
});
....
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! That works very well. I ended up using the createSelect() in my module.export and it prints my page for me.

Comment: Now the issue is that inside of the for loop were it is printing the <li>Hockey Jerseys</li>. I need that to print the groupName of each group from the database. As far as I have read it should be pretty simple but my testing has yet to give positive results. 

it should look something like this I believe dd+="<li><a href='#'>groups.groupName[i]</a></li>

I obviously am still testing and searching for an answer. But any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Glad i could help :) the dd line should look like this `dd+="<li><a href='#'>" + groups[i].groupName + "</a></li>";`